# How can I mathematically compare two measurements to improve accuracy?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, mathematical-modeling, data-analysis

I have two different techniques for measuring geolocation accuracy. I am asked to **combine** two different measurements in any way that might improve accuracy. Say I have an error of n1 using measurements A and an error of n2 using measurements B. Can I do better than both n1 and n2 by using both sets of information? 
Any suggestions or techniques that could be implemented in Python or MATLAB are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look up Kalman filtering. It not only allows you to do sensor fusion to improve your estimations, but if you have an underlying model for your system you can also incorporate that information to supplement your measurements. Edit: This technique assumes you can well approximate your errors as normally distributed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is to use the weighted mean value
$$
\bar X = \frac{\sum_i w_i X_i}{\sum_i w_i} 
$$
where the weights $w_i$ are the inverse variance, $w_i = 1/\sigma^2_i$.